# Retrieve a local JSON feed with jQuery

Tags: jquery, json, jsonp

I'm trying to use jQuery to retrieve a local JSON feed.

For some reason, this below works with an external url, but not with localhost:49171. Not sure what I'm doing wrong.

Thanks!

```
var url = "http://localhost:49171/Service1.svc/GetAllHomePageLineItems";

 $.jsonp({
      url: url,
      callbackParameter: "callback",
      cache: true,
      dataType: 'json',
      success: onSuccess,
      error: function () {
        onError()
      }
    });

function onError() {
  alert("error");
}

function onSuccess(data) {
  alert(data);
}
```

Comment: What you get if you directly access the url? and is it entering any of your callback functions when you are making ajax call?

Comment: What does your console say?

Comment: I've always had problems loading `AJAX` locally. Perhaps somebody here can assist further.

Comment: If I directly access the url, I can see the JSON, formatted properly.

Comment: Console is not reporting any errors

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out. It was a problem with Cross Domain AJAX Calling. I had to add a global.asax.cs file to my WCF web service that ws generating the JSON and enabled Cross Domain AJAX Calling.

From global.asax.cs -

```
private void EnableCrossDomainAjaxCall() {
        HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin",
                      "*");

        if (HttpContext.Current.Request.HttpMethod == "OPTIONS") {
            HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods",
                          "GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS");
            HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers",
                          "Content-Type, Accept");
            HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Max-Age",
                          "1728000");
            HttpContext.Current.Response.End();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using the $.getJson() function instead of jsonp?

http://api.jquery.com/jquery.getjson/

Comment: I have tried using $.getJson(), I get an error because the url is on a different port.

Comment: Is this script living on the same server (localhost) as the JSON feed?  I'm thinking you are running into cross-site-scripting issues.